# Need some help with fastboot to install twrp on moto g pure

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I am trying to root the phone, by following the instructions [here](https://unofficialtwrp.com/twrp-3-5-0-root-motorola-moto-g-fast/). I did unlock OEM and am able to see my device. But can not flash to recovery. So I tried booting twrp first but that does not work for me either. I did see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/211996/cant-flash-custom-twrp-recovery-image-on-motorola-moto-g7-power-phone) link and the comment about using the stock boot image. I have not tried that yet since my issue is slightly different. Thanks in advance for any advice. I am doing all this on Fedora platform.

```
sudo ./fastboot devices
[sudo] password for ****: 
####### Motorola Fastboot Interface

sudo ./fastboot boot recovery.img
[sudo] password for *****: 
Sending 'boot.img' (42408 KB)                      OKAY [  1.581s]
Booting                                            (bootloader) Command is not support
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
sudo ./fastboot flash /recovery recovery.img
Sending '/recovery' (42408 KB)                     OKAY [  1.676s]
Writing '/recovery'                                (bootloader) Invalid partition name /recovery
FAILED (remote: '')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Comment: The partition name is `recovery` (without slash), not `/recovery`.

Comment: some devices don't have recovery partition. temporary flash twrp into boot partition instead (slot B), switch active slot, boot into twrp, *Menu > Advanced > Install Recovery Ramdisk* (slot A), don't forget copy slot A > slot B to restore boot.img

Comment: beware the link you shared is for Qualcomm (rav). yours is MediaTek SoC ([ellis](https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/moto/ellis/official))

Comment: @Andrew I tried w/o slash and same result.

Comment: @alecxs I tried to boot; the output is in the post. Thank you for info on Media Tek. I did not know that. If I mistyped something, please let me know?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device link says to do something with Groupdev if you are using Ubuntu. I have not given that fastboot devices gives me an output.

Comment: I doubt you actually have TWRP for *your* device (code name **ellis**?) therefore root it by patching boot.img without TWRP

Comment: @alecxs thanks. I think the steps are https://android.stackexchange.com/a/212029/374168 . The comment also says Magisk is an option. Do you agree? I can not get over how the errors seem to be due to the wrong command. Am I wrong? I posted a question in the Motorola forum.

Comment: @alecxs it looks like even if I root it, with Magisk or a patch I can not flash it a costume rom. According to https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/moto-g-pure-xt2163-4-vs-xt2163-2-lte-bands.4368073/

Comment: if bootloader is unlockable you can boot GSI https://www.xda-developers.com/dsu-sideloader-boot-custom-android-gsi

Comment: @alecxs wow sounds like exactly what I need. I'll try it. Thank you.